Selecting an Inductor for Boost Converter
I am trying to design a boost converter on my own, but I am having the following question.
I have searched for it, but I did not find a similar one. Sorry in advance if it is already posted.
The thing is, I am designing a 2-Steps boost converter (from 48 V to 200 V, and from 200 V to 400 V). The idea is to be able to output 500 W (1.25 A).
After calculations, supposing I am using following calculations parameters:

Frequency 450 kHz
Ripple current 40%

We would get an estimated duty of 0.5 for the 2nd step, 2.51 A for the 2nd Inductor and ripple of 1 A p-p with 222 µH.
With this example calculations, I just surfed in Digikey, Mouser, etc, and I found something that I do not quite understand.
There is not published the “Withstand Voltage” parameter in the search (also looking in component's Datasheet, like Würth, I do not find that parameter).
Why is that so? Doesn't it matter the applied voltage? Using a small inductor's package would surely lead to a short, thus destroying the component.
So in the end, my question is: Expecting for example an applied voltage of 200 V on Inductor, how should I select it appropriately?
Thank you in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

They don't specify inductor voltages because it's a wire.  Since you are doing high voltage, you'll just have to make sure to get a part with the lead spacing for your project.

Not an answer to your question, but a transformer-based approach seems more appropriate for your requirements.

I’d second @Mosfet’s suggestion of a transformer. Wurth have applications engineers around the world to answer questions like yours for their products.

Interesting, I did not think about that possibility. Thank you very much for your tipp, I will surely take that approach!

Inductors do indeed have a voltage specificaton.
For instance, I just googled "wurth inductor" and selected one:
https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/74477009.pdf
The linked inductor has a 120V rating.
You should, indeed, worry about such a thing at high voltages.
Generally inductors are wound with enameled wire (magwire/magnet wire) and if I recall correctly that wire is usually said to be 350V or 500V rated.
If your inductor has no such rating, i suggest you look for one that does, or (i don't suggest) you can decide the risk is worthwhile and any failure of the inductor would be protected by, say, a fuse.

Thank you for your answer. In that case they specify it, but in other models they do not. It resulted curious for me, because I expect to see always the max. allowed voltage, as making it big enough can break through the isolation.
For example Coilcraft includes it in the search parameters, which is pretty good, but other manufacturers just ignore it.
Due to this fact, I am facing some difficulties selecting a model, as I do not know which voltage they can hold (if not specified in datasheet).

@user22603186, i would think if something is not specified that you should assume it has weak performance of that particular spec.     That said: a medical/aviation/aerospace/automotive/locomotive/etc./etc. engineer would never consider using such an unspecified inductor in a high voltage circuit.  But a cowboy engineer might -- i mean it's just enameled wire around a ferrite core, what are the odds it would cause problems. Again, if your circuit is fused, maybe it's OK.  I come from high (ish) reliability industries, so i would err on the side of caution.  but the choice is yours :)

I've seen some datasheets list this as Operating Voltage. It's usually there somewhere.
